# mysql_real_escape_string shortcut

Tags: php, mysql

i have an array with around 10 key values. which is the best way to add mysql_real_escape_string to all of them ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy way to apply a function to an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270303/easy-way-to-apply-a-function-to-an-array)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$escaped_array=array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',$array);
```

Look at [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Comment: wow. php has a default function :) my respect for PHP has go up further :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create short-cut method.. something like this ..

```
function mres($v){
    return mysql_real_escape_string($v);
}
```

and you can use mres as a function.

Comment: using array_map is easier and built in function