# Automating insertion of mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

**DISCLAIMER:** I UNDERSTAND THE FUNCTIONS ARE ON TOP OF THE TO-DO-DEPRECATION LIST. ALL WARNINGS ARE JUST PREACHING TO THE CHOIR.

anyway. I have found myself in the employment of a company using the mysql_* functions. That isnt bad enough aparently because the entire thing is without `mysql_real_escape_string()` "great". All user input is unsanitzied, so naturally being the new code monkey, my job is to incorporate it into all 4.93g of php scripts. F.M.L. "So", i thought to myself, "what if i just unset the `$_REQUEST` array on each page (not sure why but they never used `$_POST` or `$_GET` once in the entire program, they literally used `$_REQUEST` everywhere.) and then reset it with `mysql_real_escape_string`?". To me, that sure beats going through 1000000000 lines of code. **SO** I sat down and wrote the function to do it. Here is where im at:

```
/*lets say input is dirty and input2 is boy*/

    echo "<br><pre>";print_r($_REQUEST);echo "</pre><br>";

$tempString = implode(',', $_REQUEST);
$tempString2 = implode(',', array_keys($_REQUEST));
$tempArray = explode(',', $tempString);
$tempArray2 = explode(',', $tempString2);
$count = count($_REQUEST);
    echo "<br><pre>";print_r($tempArray);echo "</pre><br>";

    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br><pre>";print_r($tempArray2);echo "</pre><br>";

unset($_REQUEST);
   $_REQUEST = array();
   for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
       $_REQUEST[$tempArray2[$i]] = "mysql_real_escape_string(".$tempArray[$i].")";
   }

    echo "<br><pre>";print_r($_REQUEST);echo "</pre><br>";
```

As far as i can tell it is working!:

```
Array
(
    [input] => dirty
    [input2] => boy
)


Array
(
    [0] => dirty
    [1] => boy
)



Array
(
    [0] => input
    [1] => input2
)


Array
(
    [input] => mysql_real_escape_string(dirty)
    [input2] => mysql_real_escape_string(boy)
)
```

but frankly it seems too easy. immediate issues i see are

1. it only works for `$_REQUEST[]`
2. You have to hard code it at the top of every page, even if you set it as a global function and include it
3. If one thing goes wrong...
4. mysql_* functions suck i.e. [`mysql_real_escape_string`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

as a side note, i can't even tell you how many times i have fought to switch everything from PDO, as you can imagine they dont like the amount of time that would require.

**SO**

I suppose what im bringing this here to you guys for is, a second pair of eyes. do you see any immediate issues with this? any other *immediate issues* that i missed? If you guys like this, in any way, as im sure there are other people who could use something like this (if you build it they will come), ill go aheaad and through it on github and work it into my shcedule, thanks :)

Comment: So you're looking for a `magic_quotes` alternative utilizing `m_r_e_s`? The code you came up with is quite awful, consider a recursive function to traverse each of the input arrays. That would also solve covering `$_GET` and `$_POST` in addition to `$_REQUEST`. Try [array_walk in combination with m_r_e_s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270303/easy-way-to-apply-a-function-to-an-array)

Comment: 4.93 GB of unsanitized PHP; and you still chose *not to* rewrite it?

Comment: @DreamEater thats not my choice. i wrote a 4 page paper on why it needs rewritten. in the end i dont pay the bills...

Comment: I really doubt you can automate your way out of this one. Any organization reckless enough to jam in `$_REQUEST` data without thinking will have made all kinds of assumptions that a macro replacement or function wrapper will just trash. You should audit this app with [a SQL injection testing tool](http://sqlmap.org/) to see how apocalyptically bad this code is.

Comment: @tadman if i was searching each page and replacing all the variables-in-page, i would agree with you. but as i am tearing apart the user input and just rebuilding it, it very touches the scripts.

Comment: Given the apparent condition of this application, I imagine there's no test coverage at all, which means any changes you make will have to exhaustively tested by hand to ensure they don't break anything important. Re-writing every single database query is not something to be undertaken lightly, but then again, the cost of not doing this could be staggering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, what you are currently doing makes no sense. You are literally wrapping the words `mysql_real_escape_string(...)` around user input, which is totally pointless. It does not protect against SQL injection, and it means that the word `mysql_real_escape_string` will show up all over your input.

If you were to instead *call* `mysql_real_escape_string()` on all user input, what you'd have would be an imperfect replica of `magic_quotes`, with all the issues that entails. In particular, it means that any code which does not pass user input directly to SQL (or which uses `mysql_real_escape_string` itself appropriately!) will end up displaying SQL-escaped text (e.g, `\'` all over the place).

There is no real alternative to actually going through your code and reworking it to appropriately escape user input. If you really do have 4.93 GB of PHP to work with, though, something else is horribly wrong -- no application should *ever* be that large. A codebase of that size is utterly impossible to maintain, and you would probably be best off starting over entirely (or finding a new job).

Comment: I didnt even consider magic quotes, though never using it before i know enough about it to not want to go down that ally. I do have a job interview, hell of a job at that. until then i will semi-abandon this idea and push harder than ever for PDO

Answer (score 1):

### There should be no automated insertion of mysql_real_escape_string. Period.

Just because "to reset data with mysql_real_escape_string" **is not a synonym for "to protect data from SQL injection".** By any means.

What you actually trying to do is just to re-incarnate long time despised, deprecated and already removed [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) feature.
Try to think of the reasons.
The reason was one - serial escaping is a sure way to SQL injection

Only one note.

> mysql_* functions suck i.e. mysql_real_escape_string

this statement is not true.
this honest function is all right.
It's *programmers* who are using it improperly, responsible for the any faults.