# Can I run $_POST array through a strip_tags() loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays, post

Can I run the $_POST array through a loop to get the same result as the following code?

```
$_POST['manufacturer'] = strip_tags($_POST['manufacturer']);<br>
$_POST['part_no']      = strip_tags($_POST['part_no']);<br>
$_POST['product_name'] = strip_tags($_POST['product_name']);<br>
$_POST['link']         = strip_tags($_POST['link']);<br>
```

Or is there a way to apply strip_tags() to every field in the $_POST array?

Comment: I have made these changes  $form = array_map("strip_tags", $_POST);  $form = array_map("trim", $form);  This may be a new question, can I use array_map to remove all white spaces in an array too and if so how would I write that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy way to apply a function to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270303/easy-way-to-apply-a-function-to-an-array)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$_POST = array_map("strip_tags", $_POST);
```

Comment: I'd prefer to output it to a new variable name. It's better if you leave `$_POST` itself unaltered, because it avoids any confusion later.

Comment: This is what OP wants actually, but, yes I'd recommend also to put the result in a new variable.

Comment: I have made these changes <p>$form = array_map("strip_tags", $_POST);<br>$form = array_map("trim", $form);</p><bk> This may be a new question, can I use array_map to remove all white spaces in an array too and if so how would I write that.

Comment: Yes you can write it like that ( make sure to put the php code between php tags `<?php ?>` ). You can also nest them like this  `$form = array_map("trim", array_map("strip_tags", $_POST));`

Comment: be mindful, if your array contains an element who's value is an array, this will keep the element's key in the array but make its value null

Answer (score 1):

As previously stated, `array_map()` is the function you're looking for

However, be aware that if one of your array values is itself an array, strip_tags will nullify that value. The key will remain in the parent array, but the value of that key will be null. Here's a function I use in place of array_map to avoid this. A possible use is if you have html input field arrays in your $_POST. For example, several inputs with a name like `name="hello[]"`

```
function strip_tags_array($array){
    $result=array();
    if(is_array($array)){
        foreach($array as $key=>$value){
            if(is_array($value)){
                $result[$key]=strip_tags_array($value);
            }
            else if(is_string($value)){
                $result[$key]=strip_tags($value);
            }
            else{
                $result[$key]=$value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$_POST = strip_tags_array($_POST);
```

Comment: Good start, but had to change it a bit as this made arrays out of each value even if string as per the first line in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Could not get any of the examples to work on my server. Are you folks testing solutions? 
This works for me:

`// no code
$allowcode=""; // put allowed code tags here
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { $$key=strip_tags($value, $allowcode); }
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) { $$key=strip_tags($value, $allowcode); }`

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to use any PHP inbuilt function, you can do like below:

```
    foreach($_POST AS $key=>$val)
    {
      $_POST[$key] = strip_tags($val);
    }
```